# How to host C++ Direct2D in WPF without D3DImage and HwndHost?

Tags: c++, wpf, directx, direct3d, direct2d

**Background**

I have a legacy C++ console GUI app that I'd like to integrate into WPF without any airspace issues and VM/RDP support.

My app is using Direct3D9 in C++, where the surface is integrated into WPF via a P/Invoke and used as the back buffer of a D3DImage.

**Criteria**

1. Able to overlay WPF controls on the legacy app.
2. Must work on virtual machines and RDP (no hardware acceleration/HAL)

**Problem**

Criteria 2 - A lot of my clients connect to a Windows Server 2008 R2 VM, and as such do not have access to a HAL D3D Device Type (D3DDEVTYPE_HAL). I'm forced to use D3DDEVTYPE_REF, which is so slow it's unusable.

**Your thoughts?**

I've flirted with the idea of converting my Direct3D engine to Direct2D to have better RDP/VM support, however since D3DImage fundamentally requires a Direct3D9Ex device, my interoperability between Direct2D and Direct3D is once again tied to a need for an HAL device type. I'd be forced to create my Direct3D9Ex device as D3DDEVTYPE_REF which I imagine would give poor performance. I'm open to using GDI+ if necessary.

Comment: WPF is built on DirectX9. There's no way you can get around that. Even though you can (and I have) used DX10, DX11, D2D in the native side, you still have to run through hoops to share it back to a DX9 surface. GDI+ is no better because that's not hardware accelerated anyway. Sorry if it sounds like bad news, but I've banged my head on this for a number of years and got nothing but pain. If you can use .NET 4.5 [there may be some hope](http://marcangers.com/using-d3dimage-on-remote-desktop-rdp/) though.

Comment: I'm the author of the blog post you linked. Unfortunately, even though .NET 4.5 introduced the ability to fallback to software rendering, it doesn't solve the need for the DX9 device to need a HAL device type which is missing when using a virtual machine.

Even though GDI+ is not hardware rendered, have you managed to get it to interop with WPF?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realise that was your blog! But no, I haven't bothered with GDI+, my main issue was DirectX11 and D2D and my applications really do need hardware acceleration so it was a non-starter for me.

Comment: I ran into very similar challenges when writing a specific commercial software product.  In the end, I dumped D3DImage and simply used the WriteableBitmap, using interop to write the bits.  It is completely CPU bound, and raises the CPU utilization, but provided the best synchronization, and works pretty well on a VM.

Comment: @Jeff Thanks for the tip. Are you still using Direct3D9 then? Are you using D3DDEVTYPE_REF?

Comment: Or did you switch to Direct2D instead?

Comment: I have moved completely to DX11 and Direct2D.  It took a very long while to get a solid 'foundation', however I couldn't be happier at this point.  I am looking forward to DX12.   I use to write my own WPF controls (usually deriving from UIElement or DrawingVisual depending on input needs).  I don't miss WPF in the least. Big difference in memory usage and efficiency.

Comment: Are you using DX11_1 with WARP for VM support?

Comment: Good question.  In my recent projects I haven't had to worry about VM support and have been able to get by with HAL.

Comment: Oh, that must be nice. :)

One last question, hopefully. I'm open to switching over to Direct2D. Is the idea simply getting the backbuffer pointer from the WriteableBitmap and sending it over to C++ for Direct2D rendering?

Comment: Direct2D isn't necessary.  It will just be a memmove.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79680/discussion-between-marc-a-and-jeff).